# Viewing panoramic imagery in ArcGIS

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, imagery

Is there an ArcGIS extension or utility that will view 360 degree panoramic images?  I've found utilities that are part of larger software packages for managing mobile scanning data, but all I'm after is the spherical viewing capability.

If there isn't a tool out there, does anyone know of a .NET control that I could incorporate into an ArcMap extension that will handle spherical display?

Comment: possibly useful... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6784/using-projections-to-obtain-perspective-views

Comment: Almost certainly not possible in ArcGIS.

Comment: I've seen extensions to ArcGIS that include a viewer for panoramice images.  So, it's certaily possible.

Comment: Can you please post links to these extensions?

Comment: nView from GeoNav Group is one. http://www.geonavgroup.com.

Comment: Oribt GIS also has one, but it is limited to accessing mobile scanning data and imagery through a web service published with Orbit's Publisher software.

Answer (score 1):

**[earthmine for ArcGIS](http://www.earthmine.com/Solutions?Desktop__Software)** may offer the functionality that you seek ...

> provides a dockable window within ArcMap that displays the high
>   resolution, immersive street level view alongside the traditional 2D
>   map view. Features within the geodatabase are then accurately
>   displayed on top of the panoramic imagery.